# How to back up a computer that has problems booting up?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, hard-drive-recovery

I had a computer running Vista, has RAID 1 (Mirroring RAID), but after I haven't used it for a couple of months because I got a new computer, it had problems booting up.

Sometimes it simply won't boot up.  One time it boot up, but it was very slow in responding to the mouse.  The hard drive is 300GB mirrored, and have only about 2GB free space.

Is it best to just copy everything in its hard disk and try some more (such as scandisk, create a 30GB partition, and install Win 7)

Is booting up Ubuntu 10.04 on this computer (using CD-R or DVD-R) and then mount the C: drive and an external drive, and copy everything over to the external drive one of the best ways to back up the content in this computer?

What other best methods are there?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you describe at the end of your post is what I would do.  Boot to a Linux live CD (Ubuntu 10.04 would work fine), mount the volume that has drive C and an external hard drive, and copy important files over.  You could also try putting the drive in another machine running windows, but you may have some permissions issues to get around if you do this.